# How to minify/simple display with python script execution

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

Is there a solution to execute python script in command line and display only viewport or render view.
No splash screen, no menu, no outliner, etc.

Actualy, the command line display everything :

```
blender -P .\simple.py
```

Bonus, I prefer to not modify user preferences

Thank you

Edit 1:

```
if bpy.context.preferences.view.show_splash:
    bpy.context.preferences.view.show_splash = False

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override)
            break
```

this code work but modify user preferences...

Comment: Do you know about CTRL+ALT+SPACEBAR which makes whatever view you have below your mouse fullscreen? If you force a specific context you will probably be able to do this with Python.

Comment: If found this :
`for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override)
            break`
But it doesn't hide splashscreen